# Filtering output of winget install to show only progress bar

Tags: powershell

When running

```
winget install program-name
```

Is it possible to filter the output to show only the progress bar:
[Pictured here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3rpN.png)

`Select-String` isn't possible (have tried to `-NotMatch` the results but I'm unsure how this progress bar is actually captured) and I'm unsure what to look at next to possibly do this (if possible) - any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I know of the settings.json, but I'm not sure if you can add anything for it to skip that part.

Comment: Thanks Abraham, I looked through the documentation for the winget settings.json however there's nothing relevant unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That currently isn't possible (September 2022). There are issues on the backlog to support [JSON output](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/2032) in the .exe based CLI, as well as [native PowerShell support](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/221). Native PowerShell support would provide objects out of calls which might give the ability to just display a progress bar.

Comment: I kind of want the opposite: to get output except for the progress characters because I have a script. Anyone know if that's possible?